# Content Container Overlaps Menu?

Tags: css

I'm currently working on a Joomla template using CSS divs. I have a header set up with our logo image in a div floated to the left, an adspace floated to the right, and the menu bar on the bottom.

My content is divided into three div columns that are contained in "container.": the left column is floated left, the center is not floated, and the right is floated to the right.

The problem is the "container" for the three content divs is overlapping the menu, as you can see in this image: http://www.ndpstudentcouncil.org/images/shot1.png

Here's the HTML code:

```
> <body> <div id="backdrop">  <div
> id="wrapper">   <div id="header">
>    <div id="topimage">    </div>
>    <div id="adspace1"><jdoc:include
> type="modules" name="Ad Space #1" />
>    This will be the location for our
> "newsflash" items.    </div>
> 
>    <div id="ddtopmenubar"
> class="mattblackmenu">
>     <ul>
>     <li><a href="http://www.ndpstudentcouncil.org">Home</a></li>
>     <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/new.htm" rel="ddsubmenu1">DHTML</a></li>
>     <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/"
> rel="ddsubmenu2">CSS</a></li>
>     <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/">Forums</a></li>
>     <li><a href="http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/"
> rel="ddsubmenu3">Web Tools</a></li>
>     </ul>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddlevelsmenu.js">
>     ddlevelsmenu.setup("ddtopmenubar", "topbar")
> //ddlevelsmenu.setup("mainmenuid",
> "topbar|sidebar")
>     </script>
>     <ul id="ddsubmenu1" class="ddsubmenustyle">
>     <li><a href="#">Item 1a</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Item 2a</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Item Folder 3a</a>
>      <ul>
>      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1a</a></li>
>      </ul>
>     </li>
>     <li><a href="#">Item 4a</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Item Folder 5a</a>
>      <ul>
>      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.1a</a></li>
>      <li><a href="#">Item Folder 5.2a</a>
>       <ul>
>       <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.1a</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.2a</a></li>
>       </ul>
>      </li>
>      </ul>
>     </a>
>     </li>
>     <li><a href="#">Item 6a</a></li>
>     </ul>    </div>   </div>
>      <div id="container">    <script language="javascript">
>     matchHeight=function(){
>     var divs,contDivs,maxHeight,divHeight,d;
>     // get all <div> elements in the document
>     divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
>     contDivs=[];
>     // initialize maximum height value
>     maxHeight=0;
>     // iterate over all <div> elements in the document
>     for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
>     // make collection with <div> elements with class attribute
> 'container'
>     if(/\bcontainer\b/.test(divs[i].className)){
>     d=divs[i];
>     contDivs[contDivs.length]=d;
>     // determine height for <div> element
>     if(d.offsetHeight){
>     divHeight=d.offsetHeight;
>     }
>     else if(d.style.pixelHeight){
>     divHeight=d.style.pixelHeight;
>     }
>     // calculate maximum height
>     maxHeight=Math.max(maxHeight,divHeight);
>     }
>     }
>     // assign maximum height value to all of container <div> elements
>     for(var i=0;i<contDivs.length;i++){
>     contDivs[i].style.height=maxHeight;
>     }
>     }
>     // execute function when page loads
>     window.onload=function(){
>     if(document.getElementsByTagName){
>     matchHeight();
>     }
>     }
>     </script>    <div id="left">
>     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" />    </div>    <div
> id="middle">
>     <jdoc:include type="component" />    </div>    <div id="right">
>     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" />
>     </div>
>   </div>
>      <div id="footer" class="clear"><jdoc:include
> type="modules" name="footer" />
>    &copy; 2010 NDP Student Council<br
> />Website Development Subcommitee
>   </div>  </div> </div> </body>
```

The CSS:

```
> #backdrop {   width:100%;  height:100%;  background: #FFFFFF
> url(../images/gradient.jpg) repeat-x;
> }
> 
> #wrapper {  margin:auto;  width:95%;  height:95%;  border-right:thick solid
> black;  border-bottom:thick solid
> black;  border-top:thick solid black;
>  border-left:thick solid black;
>  background-color:white; }
> 
> #header {  height:131px;  width:100%;  background-color: #FFFFFF;
>  border-bottom:thick solid black; }
> 
> #topimage {  float:left;  height:131px;  width:63%;
>  background-image:
> url("../images/ndps2.png");
>  background-repeat:no-repeat; }
> 
> #adspace1 {  float:right;  width:27%;  height:131px; }
> 
> #container {  clear:both; }  
> #left{  width:20%;  float:left;  padding:5px;  text-align:center;  }
> 
> #middle{  width:60%;  padding:5px;  text-align:center;  }
> 
> #right{  float:right;  width:20%;  padding:5px;  text-align:right;  }  
> #footer {  border-top:thick solid black;  width:100%;
>  text-align:center; }   .clear {
>  clear:both;  }
```

Here is the CSS for the menu itself, which is from DynamicDrive.com:

```
> .mattblackmenu ul{ margin: 0; padding:
> 0; font: bold 12px Verdana;
> list-style-type: none; border-bottom:
> 1px solid gray; background: #414141;
> overflow: hidden; width: 100%;
> clear:both; }
> 
> .mattblackmenu li{ display: inline;
> margin: 0; }
> 
> .mattblackmenu li a{ float: left;
> display: block; text-decoration: none;
> margin: 0; padding: 6px 8px; /*padding
> inside each tab*/ border-right: 1px
> solid white; /*right divider between
> tabs*/ color: white; background:
> #414141;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try floating all of the three columns left, then just set margins to space them.

CSS does exactly what it says on the tin, the styles cascade, and so does the html. If you float everything left, they will naturally stack. This will make your life much easier.

Be careful of the IE6 double margin bug though - http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

Comment: When I float all three columns left, the far right column is placed underneath the first column. I don't know why that would be, considering I was able to float both the header image and "newsflash content" left at the top.

In terms of the container for the three content columns, are those properties correct? I have clear:both and overflow:hidden as properties of the wrapper for the three content columns. I call it "container" in the code.

I would honestly prefer to make the site more fluid than static. We have plans for a mobile site based off of this one, too.

Comment: Yes the column would naturally go below. This will be because the total width and margins of the columns exceed the width of their container. Try reducing the width and it will be fixed.

Again, be wary of the IE6 double margin bug, this will add a hidden width to the pages.